# SQL-Server: What is a good way to aggregate on different columns within the same query?

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

I'm using a SQL query to generate a count of row repeats. The SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  Category,
  COUNT(Category) AS Count
FROM
  TableA
GROUP BY
  Category
```

Which results in a table that looks like this:

```
Category  | Count
typeA     | 4
typeB     | 6
typeC     | 1
etc       | 9
```

Is it possible, within the same query to have an aggregation of the Aggregated rows? I would like to sum the Count column to get a percentage of each Category's contribution to the total. I.e. I'd like to produce the following table:

```
Category  | Count  | Perc of Total
typeA     | 4      | result of (4/20)*100 
typeB     | 6      | result of (6/20)*100
typeC     | 1      | result of (1/20)*100
etc       | 9      | result of (9/20)*100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
SELECT
  Category,
  COUNT(Category) AS Count,
  COUNT(Category)/ cast((SELECT COUNT(Category) FROM TableA) AS DECIMAL) * 100 as Perc
FROM
  TableA
GROUP BY
  Category
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use window functions:

```
Select Category,
    Count(Category) As [Count],
    Count(Category)*100.0 / Sum(Count(Category)) Over () As Perc
  From TableA
  Group By Category;
```